# How to merge new files (Changeset Number) into another branch Using C#

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, tfvc

I need to create windows forms app for merge new changes ( changeset number) from one branch to another branch in tfvc using c# code.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: any reason for not using visual studio?

Comment: Refer this article. http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2006/11/merging-and-resolving-conflicts-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the using the [**Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi Namespace**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet) in your C# program.

You also can try call the related [**TFVC commands**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops) in your C# program to merge the changes.